# How to resolve a "cppcoreguidelines-pro-type-cstyle-cast" error in C++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, clang

I'm working on C++ with Visual Studio 2015 64-bit and Clang as my compiler.

I tried to convert a `string` to `unsigned char*` with the code below:

```
string content = "some content from file";
unsigned char* m_Test = (unsigned char*)content.c_str();
```

However, this resulted in an error when I tried to build the project:

> error: do not use C-style cast to convert between unrelated types
>   [cppcoreguidelines-pro-type-cstyle-cast,-warnings-as-errors]

Any idea how I can work around it? Really appreciate it if you can shed some light.

Comment: You're compiling with some funky setting that rejects valid code because it violates somebody's notion of good style.

Comment: This _somebody_ is nobody less than Bjarne Stroustrup and Herb Sutter. The [C++ Core Guidelines](http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines) are backed by the same Commitee that is responsible for this very language.

Comment: @PeteBecker given that the C style cast hides a removal of `const` behind `char *` -> `unsigned char *`, I would call those settings "helpful", not "funky"

Comment: @Caleth -- a **warning** could be "helpful". Refusing to compile is funky.

Comment: @PeteBecker `-warnings-as-errors`

Comment: @Caleth -- I don't know why you're addressing that comment about a compiler setting to me. I'm not the one whose valid code is being rejected. In any event, don't take this question down a rathole just because you think turning warnings into errors is a good thing. Some people don't agree with that.

Comment: @PeteBecker The message helpfully tells what setting caused it. OP asked for warnings as errors, and got one.

Comment: @Caleth -- re: "OP asked" -- the question doesn't say that. Don't assume that every programmer knows all the details of how compilers are invoked.

Comment: @PeteBecker The only detail we have is the setting is on. Either they turned it on themselves, or their environment defaulted it. Perhaps because someone who does understand wants "this does something, but not what you think it does" to fail loudly

Comment: @Caleth -- indeed. Which is why it's important to **explain** what's going on when someone writes **valid** code and the compiler rejects it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In modern C++ the standard cstyle casts should not be used, because they are error prone. To be able to cast from `const char *` returned by `.c_str()` method of the `string`. You need to be tough on compiler. So much so, that `reinterpret_cast` is needed. Even then you need to preserve the constness. That can be casted away as well. So the code would look like this:

```
string content = "some content from file";
const unsigned char* m_Test = reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(content.c_str());
```

The `reinterpret_cast` just tells the compiler *"From now on, treat this data as stated."*

Answer (score 3):

You have two (or 3) options:

1) Replace the C-style cast with the appropriate C++ cast (`static_cast`, `const_cast`, `reinterpret_cast` or `dynamic_cast`).

2) (better option) Find a way to write your code where a cast is not needed in the first place.

3) Ignore/suppress the warning (not what *I* would recommend, though it *is* an option).

Answer (score -1):

You can use the C++ cast way with `static_cast`:

EDIT: As pointed out in the comments, you also need a `const_cast` for your particular case:

```
string content = "some content from file";
unsigned char* m_Test = static_cast<unsigned char*>(const_cast<char*>(content.c_str()));
```

Comment: Static cast wont work, because you cannot cast `const char *` to `unsigned char *`

Comment: @Xatyrian Thanks for the advice. I've tried your code, but it seems static_cast has been recognised as "invalid type conversion".

Comment: @ChangeMyName there was a typo in the const_cast. Have you tried with the fixed version by Caleth ?

Comment: @Xatyrian Yes, I have. The code is rejected as invalid type conversion. When I tried to build it, I've got a further explanation "error: static_cast from 'char *' to 'unsigned char *' is not allowed [clang-diagnostic-error]". But I doubt it is the user-defined style that prevents it from build, rather than the code is wrong.